# While converting number of seconds to time format got wrong answer

Tags: javascript

When I convert number of seconds `165` to time format like `02:45` I got wrong answer 1 hour plus in hour part `3:45`.
I don't know where is actual problem is.

```js
console.log(ConvertStringToTimeFormat(165));

function ConvertStringToTimeFormat(timeString) {

        var timeFormat = "";

        if (timeString != null && timeString != null != "") {

            if (Math.round((parseInt(timeString) / 60)) > 0)
                timeFormat += Math.round((parseInt(timeString) / 60)) + ":";
            else
                timeFormat += "00:";

            if ((parseInt(timeString) % 60) > 0)
                timeFormat += (parseInt(timeString) % 60);
            else
                timeFormat += "00";
        }
        else {
            timeFormat = "00:00";
        }

        return timeFormat;
    }
```

And also when number of seconds is 125 then I got `2:5` as answer but I need `02:05`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ angry downvoters specify the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array for the parts and get the padded strings and join the result with `:`.

```js
function convert(min) {
    return [Math.floor(min / 60), min % 60].map(function (a) { return ('00' + a).slice(-2); }).join(':');
}

console.log(convert(165));
```

ES6

```js
function convert(min) {
    return [Math.floor(min / 60), min % 60].map(a => ('00' + a).slice(-2)).join(':');
}

console.log(convert(165));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: The best answer here.

Comment: @Kinduser I disagree. It fails to answer OP's question and instead provides a different solution. This isn't [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Huh, I didn't notice that it returns a different solution. But the method is quite well.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, it is more a question of the whole approach of op. for example, it lacks understanding of division and rounding vs flooring, DRY and KISS princople and wrong naming of function, which leads to exactly different assuming what it does. last, but .. the expected string, the check for `null` and to much deep if clauses, so yes, a codereview could help.

Comment: ES6: const convert = (min) => [Math.floor(min / 60), min % 60].map(a => ('00' + a).slice(-2)).join(':')

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Math.round function, you should know that your value will be rounded to up if the decimals are greater than or equal to 5.
Let's simulate it:

```
165/60 = 2,75
```

It will round to up: 3!

Use Math.floor instead and your problem's solved.

```
console.log(ConvertStringToTimeFormat(165));

function ConvertStringToTimeFormat(timeString) {

        var timeFormat = "";

        if (timeString != null && timeString != null != "") {

            if (Math.floor((parseInt(timeString) / 60)) > 0)
                timeFormat += Math.floor((parseInt(timeString) / 60)) + ":";
            else
                timeFormat += "00:";

            if ((parseInt(timeString) % 60) > 0)
                timeFormat += (parseInt(timeString) % 60);
            else
                timeFormat += "00";
        }
        else {
            timeFormat = "00:00";
        }

        return timeFormat;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Where you're using `Math.round()`, it's rounding up 2.75 to 3. You should use `Math.floor()` instead.

```js
console.log(ConvertStringToTimeFormat(165));

function ConvertStringToTimeFormat(timeString) {

        var timeFormat = "";

        if (timeString != null && timeString != null != "") {

            if (Math.floor((parseInt(timeString) / 60)) > 0)
                timeFormat += Math.floor((parseInt(timeString) / 60)) + ":";
            else
                timeFormat += "00:";

            if ((parseInt(timeString) % 60) > 0)
                timeFormat += (parseInt(timeString) % 60);
            else
                timeFormat += "00";
        }
        else {
            timeFormat = "00:00";
        }

        return timeFormat;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round` because `165/60` in `Math.round` is 3 but you want `2`. So, Make use of `Math.floor` to find previous integer value.

```js
console.log(ConvertStringToTimeFormat(165));

function ConvertStringToTimeFormat(timeString) {

        var timeFormat = "";

        if (timeString != null && timeString != null && timeString!= "") {
            if (Math.round((parseInt(timeString) / 60)) > 0)
                timeFormat += Math.floor((parseInt(timeString) / 60)) + ":";
            else
                timeFormat += "00:";

            if ((parseInt(timeString) % 60) > 0)
                timeFormat += (parseInt(timeString) % 60);
            else
                timeFormat += "00";
        }
        else {
            timeFormat = "00:00";
        }

        return timeFormat;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) rather than [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), the later returns `The value of the given number rounded to the nearest integer`.

And for the format problem, try the following code:

```js
console.log(ConvertStringToTimeFormat(125));

function formatHourOrMinute(hom) {
  return ("0" + hom).slice( - 2);
}

function ConvertStringToTimeFormat(timeString) {
        if (timeString) {
            var timeInt = parseInt(timeString);
            var hour = Math.floor(timeInt / 60);
            var minute = timeInt % 60;
            return formatHourOrMinute(hour) + ":" + formatHourOrMinute(minute);
            
        } else {
            return "00:00";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code using skinning a bit:

```
const ConvertStringToTimeFormat = (minutes) => ("00" + Math.floor(minutes / 60)).slice(-2) +":"+ ("00" + (minutes % 60)).slice(-2)

console.log(ConvertStringToTimeFormat(165))
```

Comment: well, Nina answered while I was doing it, so just use hers

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You have a lot of unnecessary code there:

```js
function minutesToHours(min) {
   var minutes = min % 60;
   var hours = (min-minutes)/60;
   minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
   hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
   return hours+':'+minutes;
}

console.log(minutesToHours(165));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @RAJNIKPATEL :)